# Select first occurring value in column B to correspond to the value in column A SQL

Tags: sql

I am a bit stuck with a bit of SQL. I have two tables (A) Causes & (B) Cause Categories. Causes is a table full of nonprofit organizations and cause categories houses their corresponding "cause category". The trouble I am having is that there are multiple cause categories per cause, however, I want to retrieve just the first listed cause category so that there is only one cause row with one category.

Current State

```
**Cause**
Zidisha
Feeding America
NAACP
```

This is what I am getting when I left join the two tables

```
**Cause**             **Category** 
Zadisha           Economic Empowerment
Feeding America   Financial Support
Feeding America   Goods/ Service
NAACP             Human Rights
NAACP             Education
```

Ideal State

```
**Cause**             **Category** 
    Zadisha           Economic Empowerment
    Feeding America   Financial Support
    NAACP             Human Rights
```

Something that I have already tried is using first_value and partion to isolate a single category per cause.

```
SELECT c.id AS cid
, c.name AS cause
, cc.name as cause_cat
, first_value(cc.name) over (partition by cid order by cause_cat nulls last) as primary_cause_category
FROM causes c
LEFT JOIN cause_category_rel rel
    ON foreign_id = rel.cause_id
LEFT JOIN cause_categories cc
    ON rel.cause_category_id = cc.id
WHERE cause_cat is not null
GROUP BY cid, cause, cause_cat
```

And the results are:

```
   **Cause**             **Category**         **Primary Category**
    Zadisha           Economic Empowerment.     Economic Empowerment
    Feeding America   Financial Support         Financial Support
    Feeding America   Goods/ Service            Financial Support
    NAACP             Human Rights              Human Rights
    NAACP             Education                 Human Rights
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this result? I can answer any clarifying questions as well. Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "first".  SQL table represent *unordered* tables.  Ordering is determined by one or more columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I assign it a row number and order that accordingly, is there a way to characterize first? I have used first_value with partition to grab the "first" value for each cause, but I need to find a way to join that result to the main cause table.

Comment: Have you tried with a group by on Cause ?

Comment: @Atchiiii Joining those two tables creates multiple values for the cause, a group doesn't work because it cant merge multiple string values

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what your schema is outside of the sample data above, i.e., whether you have any table IDs or other elements.  However based strictly on your sample data, you could use a window function and order by the category name alphabetically to get the first record (as below).  If you don't want to use the category name, you could switch it to `ORDER BY NEWID()` to generate a random ID on the fly if you're just looking to get any random single category to flatten the data.

```
drop table if exists #cause
drop table if exists #causeCategory

create table #cause (causeName varchar(20))
create table #causeCategory (causeName varchar(20), category varchar(50))

insert into #cause
values
('Zidisha'),
('Feeding America'),
('NAACP')

insert into #causeCategory
values
('Zidisha',           'Economic Empowerment'),
('Feeding America',   'Financial Support'),
('Feeding America',   'Goods/ Service'),
('NAACP' ,            'Human Rights'),
('NAACP',             'Education')

;with cte
as (
    SELECT 
    c.causeName,
    cc.category,
    row_number() over (partition by c.causeName order by cc.category) as rn
    FROM #cause c
    LEFT JOIN #causeCategory cc
        ON c.causeName = cc.causeName
    GROUP BY c.causeName, cc.category
    )
select causeName, category
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT  c.id AS cid
        ,c.name AS cause
        ,(
             SELECT TOP 1
                    cc.name
             FROM   cause_category_rel AS rel
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN cause_categories AS cc ON rel.cause_category_id = cc.id
             WHERE  c.foreign_id = rel.cause_id
                    AND cause_cat IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY
                    cause_cat
         ) AS primary_cause_category
FROM    causes AS c;
```